# Any guidelines to follow to design database Metadata Repository?

Tags: database, modeling

I would like to design a metadata repository for the internal database. The repository should be able to provide simeple answers to questions like - which tables have what type of data and what are the table relationships ? Any industry standard guidelines that I should follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read recently that the SQL 92 standard mandates databases have an INFORMATION_SCHEMA meta data repository and, Googling a little, I see that it supports both of your example questions.